# Return only changed columns between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have a normal table structure. Like the one below

```
TableName_OID|GlobalKeyColumn(or foreign key)|Column2| ... |ColumnN|CreateBy|CreateDate|ModifyBy|ModifyDate|IsActive|IsUpdated|UpdateOfTableName_OID
```

I have written a **before update trigger** which will take the last row (with inserted.TableName_OID) and insert into the table with its [IsUpdated] = 1 and [UpdateOfTableName_OID] = TableName_OID (or I can insert a row that will only have changed columns' values but I dont know how).

For showing the whole history of table wrt a [GlobalKeyColumn] I have something in my mind. If I go with the first option (inserting a whole row), I will have to run a cursor on the resultset (for a certain GlobalKeyColumn) comparing each row with it's previous one and show only the changed columns.

What I need help with both the options is how to compare each column of a row to its previous one's. I mean, I can do it manually, but is there any generic thing in SQL Server that could compare all the columns in a row to it's previous one?

Comment: You need to do it manually, alas, unless you use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I thought I could do something using sys.columns. Was on deadline so did it manually.